# -[NSRunLoop runUntilDate:] consumes 100% CPU

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsrunloop, external-accessory

I'm building an application that interfaces with external accessories (thus with the ExternalAccessory framework).

Part of this interfacing is waiting for events to occur on the in/out streams to the external device.

For that, I use a thread, and block it in the NSRunLoop to make sure it keeps waiting for events.

```
- (void)eventThreadSelector
{
    // Setting up the environment
    self.session = <got the EASession>;

    self.inputStream = [self.session inputStream];
    self.inputStream.delegate = self;
    [self.inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.inputStream open];

    self.outputStream = [self.session outputStream];
    self.outputStream.delegate = self;
    [self.outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.outputStream open];

    // Waiting for events coming from the NSStreams
    while (![[NSThread currentThread] isCancelled]) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:.1]];
    }

    // When the device is unplugged, 
    [self.inputStream close];
    [self.inputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    self.inputStream.delegate = nil;
    self.inputStream = nil;

    [self.outputStream close];
    [self.outputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    self.outputStream.delegate = nil;
    self.outputStream = nil;

    self.session = nil;
}

- (void)accessoryDidDisconnect:(EAAccessory *)accessory
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"EID: Got accessoryDidDisconnect notification on main thread? %i", [[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]);

    [self.eventThread cancel];
    self.eventThread = nil;
}
```

So far, all of this works great :) But there's one thing I can't wrap my head around.

When I unplug the external device, the processor briefly jumps to 100% and above. I've done a little bit of investigation, and this seems to be linked to the NSRunLoop going nuts. That CPU peak has a negative impact on the UI :(

How can I avoid this processor usage peak?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I do have the exact same issue.

Comment: Ooh, that’s a good question. That specific project was successful and I don’t remember that issue staying. I would guess it’s either fixable, or there are other ways to do this. So I can’t really tell you better than “keep looking, there’s a solution”. Good luck :)